# azure devops: How to end a build successfully with warnings when a step fails

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When a certain step in my build fails I would like the build to end there, but show success with warnings instead of fail. I know continueOnError has this effect, but it still executes the subsequent steps. I would like to exit early instead of executing those but still keep the success with warnings status. How can I achieve this?

```
    - task: DownloadBuildArtifacts@0
      displayName: 'Download build artifacts'
      continueOnError: true
      inputs:
        artifactName: 'build-artifacts'
        buildType: 'current'
        downloadType: 'single'
        downloadPath: '$(Agent.BuildDirectory)/s'
    - task: myNextTask@0
      inputs:...
```

In other words, if downloadBuildArtifact has nothing to download I would like the pipeline to not execute myNextTask, but end the process with a 'success with warnings'

Comment: Why not have a script in between checking the folder and then it can exit and write a warning if needed?

Answer (score 0):

There's no easy way to do that with just conditions.

I suspect you can get it to work as follows:

- Mark your Download Artifact task to succeed on error.
- Add a script task that checks whether the artifact is present and sets the value of a variable accordingly.
- Add a condition to the following tasks to only run when the variable has a certain value.

Do be careful though, if the Download Artifact task fails for another reason, like connection issues, interruptions, permissions etc, the error will be hidden.

An alternate route would be to add a script prior to the Download Artifact task that checks the presence of the desired artifact by querying the REST API. It can then set a variable which is used as a condition for all following tasks.